# EJS not able to render page due to class declaration

Tags: node.js, ejs, templating-engine

```
<header class="main-header">
<nav class="main-header__nav">
    <ul class="main-header__item-list">
        <li class="main-header__item"><a class="<%= path === '/' ? 'active' : '' %>" href="/">Shop</a></li>
        <li class="main-header__item"><a class="<%= path === '/admin/add-product' ? 'active' : '' %>" href="/admin/add-product">Add Product</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

When I try to render the page in my node js application I am getting an error. Saying there is an error

I am not so used to writing ejs but when I remove the `class="<%= path === '/' ? 'active' : '' %>"` in the navigation.ejs it seems to work

[image]

Error Image

Comment: The syntax is valid. Are you sure that `path` is set? What's the exact error output?

Comment: Have added the error message in the question

Comment: error says there is no proper closing tag for <% check at line 19 in ejs.js file

Answer (score 0):

Use `<%- include('RELATIVE/PATH/TO/FILE'); %>` to embed an EJS partial in another file.

- The hyphen `<%-` instead of just `<%` tells EJS to render raw HTML.
- The path to the partial is relative to the current file.
- and also use `;` at end of include

**Here is an example...**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <%- include('../partials/head'); %>
</head>
<body class="container">

<header>
    <%- include('../partials/header'); %>
</header>

<main>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>This is great</h1>
        <p>Welcome to templating using EJS</p>
    </div>
</main>

<footer>
    <%- include('../partials/footer'); %>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have added the semi colon for the include but it still gives the error

Comment: Ok, but as I viewed in your screenshot 5th line it's not an issue of class declaration.